# OpenCV warpPerspective with another datatype

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have a picture and a depth map that belongs to that picture, I need to have the depth of each pixel(I am using a kinect). I would like to create a panorama view with this picture and it's depth, so I used some opencv methods. This line in particular is the one that is causing a problem at the moment:

```
result = cv2.warpPerspective(imageA, H, (imageA.shape[1] + imageB.shape[1], imageA.shape[0]))
```

The problem here is, that the depthmap does not use an 8 bit presentation to indicate the depth of the pixel. It's a 32 bit integer. And the problem that I'm having here, is that this `cv2.warpPerspective()` method does not want to take this datatype. This is the error that gets thrown:

> TypeError: src data type = 8 is not supported

I could convert it to 8 bit, but that loses so much information, I cannot afford to lose that much accuracy in depth. I know it works though, when I convert it to 8 bit. So I'm guessing that I need a workaround for this, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not [`warpPerspective`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gaf73673a7e8e18ec6963e3774e6a94b87) that doesn't want to take this datatype. It's OpenCV in general, since arrays of unsigned 32bit integers are not supported.

You can have:

- 8 bit integers, signed and unsigned
- 16 bit integers, signed and unsigned
- 32 bit integers, signed only
- 32 bit floats
- 64 bit floats

The `numpy` library's arrays (which are used by the Python API) are somewhat more flexible in what they can do. Unfortunately this can sometime lead to fairly obscure errors when they're passed to OpenCV functions.

---

Unfortunately for you, using 32bit signed integers is also out of question, because [`cv::remap`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gab75ef31ce5cdfb5c44b6da5f3b908ea4) (which is used to perform the actual transformation) doesn't seem to support them. It does, however, support all the other 6 available types. Depending on the actual range of your depthmap values, either the 16 bit integers, or one of the floating point options will do.

Comment: I've been using several different methods now, none of them are perfect, but I'll get there, thank you for your information.